# Infrared selected switch statement using Arduino and Neopixels

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm having some problems putting the finishing touches on the latest project. The Idea is to have an Infrared receiver mounted on a single Arduino Uno, taking ques from a remote to select preprogramed patterns on a Neopixel strip (selection from the Neopixel Strand test)

Here is my code

```
//Always comment your code like a violent psychopath will be maintaining it and they know where you live
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>                            //Neopixel Library
#include <IRLibAll.h>                                     //IR reciever Library

IRrecvLoop myReceiver(2);                                     //IR receiver on IO pin 2
IRdecode myDecoder;                                       //Decoder object
unsigned long oldCode = 00000000;                         //Comparison variable to evaluate the execution of the 'Check' function later
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip (3,3,NEO_RGBW + NEO_KHZ800);      //Creates the Pixel strip as an object in the code

void setup() {
  strip.begin();                      //Initialise the Neopixel strip
  strip.show();                       //Initialise all pixels to 'off'
  myReceiver.enableIRIn();            // Start the IR receiver
}

void loop() {
  check();                            //Run the check function
  delay(20);                          //Delay before running the loop again by 20 milliseconds giving time to recieve signals
}

void check() {                                    //check Function: Checks for an IR signal before nominating which of the test displays to run
    if (oldCode = myDecoder.value){                    //Evaluates if the IR code recieved from the remote matches 'oldCode' and if it does....
    return;                                       //Terminates the check Function returning its values
    }                                                  
      if (myReceiver.getResults()) {
        myDecoder.decode();
        if (myDecoder.protocolNum == NEC) {  
          switch(myDecoder.value) {                                                                 //Activate this switch statement based on the value 'myDecoder' holds
            case 0xFFA25D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFFE21D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFF629D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFF22DD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFF02FD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFFC23D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFFE01F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFFA857: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFF906F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFF9867: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            case 0xFFB04F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
            
            case 0xFF6897:
              colorWipe(strip.Color(  0,   0,   0), 50);    // Black/off  "0"     
              Serial.println("0 - Black/off");    
              break;
            case 0xFF30CF:
              colorWipe(strip.Color(255,   0,   0), 50);    // Red  "1"
              Serial.println("1 - All red");    
              break;
            case 0xFF18E7:
              colorWipe(strip.Color(  0, 255,   0), 50);    // Green  "2"      
              Serial.println("2 - All green");    
              break;
            case 0xFF7A85: 
              colorWipe(strip.Color(  0,   0, 255), 50);    // Blue  "3"
              Serial.println("3 - All blue");    
              break;
            case 0xFF10EF:
              theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50); // White  "4"
              Serial.println("4 - All white");    
              break;
            case 0xFF38C7:
              theaterChase(strip.Color(127,   0,   0), 50); // Red  "5"
              Serial.println("5");    
              break;
            case 0xFF5AA5:
              theaterChase(strip.Color(  0,   0, 127), 50); // Blue   "6"
              Serial.println("6");    
              break;
            case 0xFF42BD:
              rainbow(10);                                  //      "7"
              Serial.println("7");    
              break;
            case 0xFF4AB5:
              theaterChaseRainbow(50);                      //      "8"
              Serial.println("8");    
              break;

            case 0xFF52AD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8");    break;
            case 0xFFFFFFFF: Serial.println("Please release button and reselect");         break;                          
        }
      }
    oldCode = myDecoder.value;                       //make the new button state equal the old buttonstate preventing the button from activating if statement
  }
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {        //Colour wipe test
  while(true) {
    for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {      // For each pixel in strip...
      strip.setPixelColor(i, color);              //  Set pixel's color (in RAM)
      strip.show();                               //  Update strip to match
      check();   
      delay(wait);                                //  Pause for a moment
  }
  }
}

void theaterChase(uint32_t color, int wait) {     //Theatre Chase test
  while(true) {
  for(int a=0; a<10; a++) {                       // Repeat 10 times...
    for(int b=0; b<3; b++) {                      //  'b' counts from 0 to 2...
      strip.clear();                              //   Set all pixels in RAM to 0 (off)
      for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) { // 'c' counts up from 'b' to end of strip in steps of 3...
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color);            // Set pixel 'c' to value 'color'
        check();                                  //Run the check function
      }
      strip.show();                               // Update strip with new contents
      delay(wait);                                // Pause for a moment
    }
  }
  }
}
void rainbow(int wait) {                                                            //Rainbow test function
  while(true) {                                                                     //while this function is active
  for(long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 3*65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {      //Sets differing colours for the rainbow 
    for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) {                                        //For each pixel in strip...
      int pixelHue = firstPixelHue + (i * 65536L / strip.numPixels());              //balances the colour pattern along the length of the strip
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(pixelHue)));              //run the colour pattern along the strip
      check();                                                                      //run the check function
    }
    strip.show();                                                                   //Update strip with new contents
    delay(wait);                                                                    //Pause for a moment
  }
  }
}

void theaterChaseRainbow(int wait) {
  while(true) {
  int firstPixelHue = 0;                                                            //First pixel starts at red
  for(int a=0; a<30; a++) {                                                         //Repeat 30 times...
    for(int b=0; b<3; b++) {                                                        //'b' counts from 0 to 2...
      strip.clear();                                                                //Set all pixels to off
      for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {                                   //'c' counts up from 'b' to end of strip in increments of 3, hue of pixel 'c' is offset by an amount to make one full revolution of the color wheel (range 65536) along the length of the strip (strip.numPixels() steps):
        int hue = firstPixelHue + c * 65536L / strip.numPixels();                   //create the hue variable and balance the rainbow colouring across the strip
        uint32_t color = strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(hue));                        // hue -> RGB
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color);                                              // Set pixel 'c' to value 'color'
        check();                                                                    //Run the check function
      }
      strip.show();                         // Update strip with new contents
      delay(wait);                          // Pause for a moment
      firstPixelHue += 65536 / 90;          // One cycle of color wheel over 90 frames
    }
  }
  }
}
```

The Problems

I have tried to write a loop that uses a class call to decide what is going on ("check"), I have also written another version where the switch statement is place in the loop instead. The problem from what I understand is that the IR input cannot receive whilst the loop is running (as it cannot interrupt) yet the test patterns will not play unless the loop is running. I have looked at solutions that involve using two Arduino's with either one running IR and the Neopixel respectively but unfortunately this will not match up with my brief - I need to have it running on one Arduino.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the welcome.  I would have thought that this would have come under the "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" but i realise using flowery language may have gotten people confused.

The question put blunt should have been "how else could I write this to make this work?" with the answer (after getting aid in other forums) being "write functions into classes"

I apologise for trying to use this forum to ask questions but when it was introduced to me in Uni thats what it was for and at that time it was by far the most useful and helpful place

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested - the final code to this project was...

```
    //Always comment your code like it will be maintained by a violent psychopath who knows where you live.
#include <IRLibAll.h>                                                                       //Infra Red Library
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>                                                              //Adafruit NeoPixel Library

//======== Constants =============
const int LEDpin = 3;                                                                       //IO pin for the LED strip
const int LEDcount = 3;                                                                     //Number of LED's in the strip
const int IRreceiver = 2;                                                                   //IO pin for the IRreceiver
IRrecvPCI myReceiver(IRreceiver);                                                           //Instantiate the Infra Red receiver 
IRdecode myDecoder;                                                                         //Instatiate a Decoder object (Veriable to hold the recieved data from the button press)
enum  pattern { NONE, RAINBOW_CYCLE, THEATER_CHASE, color_WIPE, SCANNER, FADE };            //Limit the results 'pattern' will accept with an enumeration

//======== Variables =============

//=====Classes and Functions =====

class neoPatterns : public Adafruit_NeoPixel                                              //A class to govern the operation of the Neopixel patterns outside of the Main loop
{
  private:
    int steps;
    uint32_t color;
           
  public:

    pattern activePattern;                                                                  //Tracks the pattern that is currently active on the strip
    unsigned long interval;                                                                 //Milliseconds between updates
    unsigned long lastUpdate;                                                               //Records the millisecond of the last update

    uint32_t color1, color2;                                                              //Variables for recording active colors
    uint16_t totalSteps;                                                                    //How many steps of the pattern have been called
    uint16_t index;                                                                         //What step within the pattern we are on

    void (*onComplete)();                                                                   //onComplete callback function - still wondering how much i need this?
    
    neoPatterns(uint16_t pixels, uint8_t pin, uint8_t type, void (*callback)())             //Class constructor to...
    :Adafruit_NeoPixel(pixels, pin, type)                                                   //initialise the Neopixel strip
    {
      onComplete = callback;      
    }

  void update()                                                                             //Function that manages updating the pattern
  {
    if((millis() - lastUpdate) > interval)                                                  //Is it time to update?
      {
      lastUpdate = millis();                                                                //Updates 'lastUpdate' to the current milli's value
      switch(activePattern)                                                                 //Switch statement to track which pattern needs its update function
        {
          case RAINBOW_CYCLE:                                                               //If rainbowCycle...
          rainbowCycleUpdate();                                                             //update rainbowCycle
          break;
  
          case THEATER_CHASE:                                                               //If theatreChase...
          theaterChaseUpdate();                                                             //update theatreChase
          break;
  
          case color_WIPE:                                                                 //if colorWipe
          colorWipeUpdate();                                                                //update colorWipe
          break;
  
          case SCANNER:                                                                     //if scanner
          scannerUpdate();                                                                  //update scanner
          break;
  
          case FADE:                                                                        //if fade
          fadeUpdate();                                                                     //update fade
          break;
  
          default:
          break;
        }
      }
  }

  void increment()                                                                          //Function for incrementing values to drive strand tests
  {
    index++;                                                                                //increment index variable
      if (index >= totalSteps)                                                              //if index is greater than or equal to totalsteps...
      {
        index = 0;                                                                          //..reset index to 0 and...
        if (onComplete != NULL)                                                             //... if onComplete has no value...
          {
            onComplete();                                                                   //...call the onComplete callback
          }
      }
  }  

  void rainbowCycle(uint8_t interval)                                                                //Rainbow Cycle strand test pattern
  {
    activePattern = RAINBOW_CYCLE;                                                          //Set current active pattern to Rainbow Cycle...
    interval = interval;                                                                    //reset interval to interval
    totalSteps = 255;                                                                       //set total step variable to 255
    index = 0;                                                                              //set index variable to 0
  }

  void rainbowCycleUpdate()                                                                 //update for Rainbow Cycle
  {
    for(int i=0; i< numPixels(); i++)                                                       //create a variable called 'i' which is equal to 0 and do loops, whilst the number of pixels in the strip is greater than i, incremeting i every loop.
    {
      setPixelColor(i, wheel(((i * 256 / numPixels()) + index) & 255));                     //set the pixel color to ...
    }
    show();                                                                          //update the orders to the Neopixel strand
    increment();                                                                            //Run the increment function
  }

  void colorWipe (uint32_t color, uint8_t interval)                                       //color wipe funtion
  {
    activePattern = color_WIPE;                                                            //update the current active pattern to color Wipe
    interval = interval;                                                                    //reset the interval variable
    totalSteps = 255;                                                                       //set the total steps variable to 255
    color1 = color;                                                                       //set color to color 1
    index = 0;                                                                              //reset the index variable to 0
  }

  void colorWipeUpdate()                                                                    //Color wipe update function
  {
    setPixelColor(index, color1);                                                           //change the pixel color to color1
    show();                                                                          //update the strand
    increment();                                                                            //run the increment function
  }

  void theaterChase(uint32_t color1, uint32_t color2, uint8_t interval)                   //Theatre Chase funtion
  {
    activePattern = THEATER_CHASE;                                                          //change the current active pattern to Theatre Chase 
    interval = interval;                                                                    //reset the interval variable 
    totalSteps = numPixels();                                                               //update the total steps variable to be equivilent to the number of pixels
    color1 = color1;                                                                      //Reset color1
    color2 = color2;                                                                      //Reset color2
    index = 0;                                                                              //Set index variable to 0
  }    

  void theaterChaseUpdate()                                                                 //Theatre Chase update function
  {
    for(int i=0; i< numPixels(); i++)                                                       //take the i variable and reset it to 0 and do loops, whilst the number of pixels in the strip is greater than i, incremeting i every loop.
      {
        if ((i + index) % 3 == 0)                                                           //if the total of I and index divide equally by 3...
          {
            setPixelColor(i, color1);                                                       //...set the pixelcolor to color 1...
          }
        else                                                                                //...otherwise... 
          {
            setPixelColor(i, color2);                                                       //set the pixel color to color 2
          }
      }
    show();                                                                          //update the neopixel strand
    increment();                                                                            //run the increment function
  }

  void scanner(uint32_t color1, uint8_t interval)                                          //Scanner function
  {
    activePattern = SCANNER;                                                                //update the active pattern to Scanner
    interval = interval;                                                                    //reset the interval variable
    totalSteps = (numPixels() - 1) * 2;                                             //set the total steps variable to by equal to twice that of the number of pixels on the strand less one 
    color1 = color1;                                                                      //reset the color1 variable 
    index = 0;                                                                              //set the index variable to 0
  }

  void scannerUpdate()                                                                      //Scanner update function
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels(); i++)                                                   //take the i variable and reset it to 0 and do loops, whilst the number of pixels in the strip is greater than i, incremeting i every loop.
    {
      if (i == index)                                                                       //if the i variable is equivilant to the index variable...
      {
        setPixelColor(i, color1);                                                          //set the pixel color to color1
      }
      else if (i == totalSteps - index)                                                     //if the i variable is equivilant to totalsteps less the value of index...
      {
        setPixelColor(i, color1);                                                           //set the pixel color to color1...
      }
      else                                                                                  //otherwise...
      {
        setPixelColor(i, DimColor(getPixelColor(i)));                                       //dim the current pixel value
      }
    }
    show();                                                                          //update the strand
    increment();                                                                            //run the increment function
  }  

  void fade(uint32_t color1, uint32_t color2, uint16_t steps, uint8_t interval)           //Fade function
  {
    activePattern = FADE;                                                                   //set the current active pattern to fade
    interval = interval;                                                                    //reset the interval variable
    totalSteps = steps;                                                                     //create a new steps variable and set it to be eqivilant to totalSteps 
    color1 = color1;                                                                      //reset color1
    color2 = color2;                                                                      //reset color2
    index = 0;                                                                              //set index to 0
  }

  void fadeUpdate()                                                                                       //Fade update function
  {
    uint8_t red = ((Red(color1) * (totalSteps - index)) + (Red(color2) * index)) / totalSteps;          
    uint8_t green = ((Green(color1) * (totalSteps - index)) + (Green(color2) * index)) / totalSteps;
    uint8_t blue = ((Blue(color1) * (totalSteps - index)) + (Blue(color2) * index)) / totalSteps;
    colorSet(Color(red, green, blue));
    show();                                                                                        //update the strand
    increment();                                                                                          //run the increment function
  }

  uint8_t Red(uint32_t color)                                                              //Red color function
  {
    return (color >> 16) & 0xFF;    
  }

  uint8_t Green(uint32_t color)                                                            //Green color function
  {
    return (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
  }

  uint8_t Blue(uint32_t color)                                                             //Blue color function
  {
    return color & 0xFF;
  }

  uint32_t DimColor(uint32_t color)                                                        //color dimming function
  {
    uint32_t dimColor = Color(Red(color) >> 1, Green(color) >> 1, Blue(color) >> 1);
    return dimColor;
  }   
  
  uint32_t wheel(byte wheelPos)                                                             //color wheeling function for the rainbow color functions
  {
    wheelPos = 255 - wheelPos;
    if(wheelPos < 85)
    {
      return Color(255 - wheelPos * 3, 0, wheelPos * 3);
    }
    else if(wheelPos < 170)
    {
      wheelPos -= 85;
      return Color(0, wheelPos * 3, 255 - wheelPos * 3);
    }
    else
    {
      wheelPos -= 170;
      return Color(wheelPos * 3, 255 - wheelPos * 3, 0);    
    }
  }
 
  void colorSet(uint32_t color)                                                           //color set function sets all colors to the same synchronus color
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < numPixels(); i++)
    {
      setPixelColor(i, color);    
    }
    show();    
  }

  void IRSelector()                                                                           //Infra Red selection function - takes action based on IR code received        
  {
    if (myDecoder.protocolNum == NEC) {                                                       //ignore any code that is not recieved from a NEC remote control 
      switch(myDecoder.value)                                                                   //Switch statement that makes a decision based upon the value recieved from the Infra Red decoder
      {
        case 0xFFA25D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;      //=====================================================================
        case 0xFFE21D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFF629D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFF22DD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFF02FD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;      // ------------- UNASSIGNED BUTTON SELECTIONS -------------------------
        case 0xFFC23D: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFFE01F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFFA857: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFF906F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFF9867: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;
        case 0xFFB04F: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8"); break;      //=====================================================================
        
        case 0xFF6897:      //"0 - All black (off)"    
          colorWipe(color, interval);     
          Serial.println("0 - Black/off");    
          break;
        case 0xFF30CF:      //"1 - All red"
          colorWipe(color, interval);    
          Serial.println("1 - All red");    
          break;
        case 0xFF18E7:      //"2 - All green" 
          colorWipe(color, interval);         
          Serial.println("2 - All green");    
          break;
        case 0xFF7A85:      //"3 - All blue"
          colorWipe(color, interval);    
          Serial.println("3 - All blue");    
          break;
        case 0xFF10EF:      //"4 - All white"
          colorWipe(color, interval); 
          Serial.println("4 - All white");    
          break;
        case 0xFF38C7:       //"5 - Rainbow Cycle"
          rainbowCycle(interval);                      
          Serial.println("5");    
          break;
        case 0xFF5AA5:       //"6 - Theater Chase"
          theaterChase(color1, color2, interval);                                 
          Serial.println("6");    
          break;
        case 0xFF42BD:       //"7 - Scanner"
          scanner(color1, interval);                                 
          Serial.println("7");    
          break;
        case 0xFF4AB5:      //"8 - Fader"
          fade(color1, color2, steps, interval);                      
          Serial.println("8");    
          break;
        
        case 0xFF52AD: Serial.println("Untethered button, please select from 0-8");    break;      //button 9 - unassigned
        case 0xFFFFFFFF: Serial.println("Please release button and reselect");         break;      //consistant repeat code

        default: 
        Serial.print(" other button   ");                                                          
        Serial.println(myDecoder.value);

      }//End of Switch
    }
  }//End of IRSelector method
}; // End of neoPatterns class

void strandComplete();                                                                         
neoPatterns strand(LEDcount, LEDpin, NEO_RGBW + NEO_KHZ800, &strandComplete);               //Neopattern object to define the strand

void setup(){   /*----( SETUP: RUNS ONCE )----*/
  Serial.begin(9600);                                                                          //engage the serial monitor
  Serial.println("IR Receiver Button Decode");                                                 //print out to the monitor
  myReceiver.enableIRIn();                                                                     //Start the receiver
  strand.begin();                                                                              //start the Neopixel strip
}/*--(end setup )---*/

void loop(){   /*----( LOOP: RUNS CONSTANTLY )----*/
  if (myReceiver.getResults())                                                                 //check to see if we have received an IR signal?
  {
    myDecoder.decode();                                                                        //Decode the recieved signal
    strand.IRSelector();                                                                              //Run the IR selection function
    myReceiver.enableIRIn();                                                                   //reset the receiver for a new code
  }
  strand.update();                                                                             //Run the update function on the Neopixel strand
}/* --(end main loop )-- */

void strandComplete()
{
    // Random color change for next scan
    strand.color1 = strand.wheel(random(255));
}`
```